# New Linux box not recognizing hostnames and its nostname is not recognized

Tags: networking

I have three Linux boxes on my home network, which are connected to my router via cat5e. I've had boxes one and two for a while, but just added box 3. For some reason box 3 doesn't want to use host names, only IP addresses, and I'm hoping y'all can help me figure out why.

If I'm logged into box 1, I can ping and connect to box 2 by name or IP address, but I can only ping or connect to box 3 by IP address. If I try box 3's name, I get the error "Name or service not known."

If I'm logged into box 2, I can ping and connect to box 1 by name or IP address, but I can only ping or connect to box 3 by IP address. If I try box 3's name, I get the error "Name or service not known."

If I'm logged into box 3, I can only ping and connect to boxes 1 and 2 by IP address. If I try using their names, I get the error "Name or service not known."

All three are on the same subnet 192.168.0.xxx.

Comment: Have you setup `named` or `avahi` on box 3? Have you a correct `/etc/resolv.conf` file?

Comment: That was it. I hadn't set up avahi! Thanks! (For some reason I can't accept the answer. Probably too new to this part of stackexchange.)

Comment: Have you setup named or avahi on box 3? Have you a correct /etc/resolv.conf file?

Comment: You cannot accept it as an answer since it was a comment, however, answer below if you wish to tick it...

Comment: Answers should not have clarifying questions in them.  If you've discovered the problem, please describe it and/or the fix in the Answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-config option requires that avahi be run on the system. This will broadcast and listen for replies on the local network without any user interaction.